# display:table using Struts action results

Tags: struts2, displaytag

I have a display:table tag using the results of a struts action that consistently says "no records to display". Logging code in the action method shows that there are 30 items in the action results.

Hoping someone can point out my error:

JSP is:

```
<s:action var="passageAction" name="list" namespace="/secure/assessment/passage">
    <s:param name="itemBankID">${param.itemBankID}</s:param>
    <s:param name="standardGuid">${param.standardGuid}</s:param>
</s:action>

<display:table id="passage" name="#passageAction.availableItems">
```

Struts Action def:

```
<action name="list" class="com.ia.controller.assessment.PassageAction" method="listPassages">
  <result name="success"/>
  <result name="error"/>
</action>
```

The last part of listPassages method which logs 30 items:

```
       this.availableItems =
                this.passageDAO.list(
                    criteria,
                    pagination,
                    showRetired,
                    excludePrompt,
                    null);
       LOGGER.info("count of items " + this.availableItems.size());
       return SUCCESS;
```

Comment: AFAIK the display tag library knows nothing about OGNL (it may now, it's been 5+ years since I've thought about it at all) and you're trying to use OGNL to reference the items. The first thing I'd try is using standard JSP EL notation for display tag's `name` attribute, but my wild guess is that will not be sufficient. That said, I'm puzzled why you'd do it this way at all, i.e., via the `<s:action />` tag. Make the call in the action you're actually using rather than a separate action--the view layer isn't a good place to aggregate the information it needs.

Comment: I am loading the results of this page into a div tag so it appears as a popup modal window. That is why the separate use of the s:action tag

Comment: I don't see how it being in a popup is related at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using the action in a jquery load on the div tag... as Dave said, too many pieces –